# How to dynamically highlight the current page in nav bar like Stackoverflow

Tags: jquery

I have a nav bar in my header.php page that I include on every page of my website. How do I add a class of current_page to the current page?

I tried

```
$('a[href="'+window.location+'"]').addClass('menu-highlight');
```

but if my GET variables are set it doesnt work, and my href's are relative url's.

One idea I have is on the php page including the file to hold a number corresponding to the page, and with Jquery change the li with that number in an attribute.

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 1):

The best practice would be to handle this in server-side code. However, if you're using absolute path links, and not full URL links, you can use

`window.location.pathname`

to exclude query string instead of

`window.location.href`

which includes it

```
window.location.href
=> "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10506079/how-to-dynamically-highlight-the-current-page-in-nav-bar-like-stackoverflow?test=foo"

window.location.pathname
=> "/questions/10506079/how-to-dynamically-highlight-the-current-page-in-nav-bar-like-stackoverflow"
```